# How do I center a form inside a centered div in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[Here is the link to the fiddle I have been working on.](http://jsfiddle.net/662xfxfu/)

I am not sure why margin 0 auto and setting a width to the form is not setting the form in the center.

```
.margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#center {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-horizontal{
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The outer div that the form is inside of is supposed to be centered and then the form is supposed to be centered inside the div.

Comment: Try different browser. It looks fine on ffox. I got div and form centered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex`

```
#center {
   display:flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Replace your code by above code and see the result.